# what is the difference between 売り場, デパート and モール

Tags: grammar

what is the difference between

売り場

デパート

モール

Comment: What is your initial understanding of them?

Answer (score 2):

**売り場** is a general place where something is being sold. It can be anything.

**デパート** literally is a department store.

And **モール** is a shopping mall.